# How to write a multi-line series of equations in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

[image]

I am trying to write those with `$\begin{equation}$` and `$\end{equation}$` but exactly this figure is not coming!

How to write those in latex s.t. it is written in picture?

Comment: If you use an equation environment, you don't need `$...$` around it. Can you show us what you have tried that does not exactly give this figure?

Comment: Those are coming but not exactly as in fig. i.e. line by line (as in the big.)

Comment: Then please show us what code you have so far. I'm sure we can help you to make them line by line.

Comment: Learn about `align*` environment.

Comment: This is something I’d use the `split` environment for: look it up in Section 3.4 of the manual of the `amsmath` package (`texdoc amsmath`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is `just-do-it-for-me` class of question.

Answer (score 7):

In the line of Yourgos's answer, and to be more specific, if you want:

- no numbering at all, use either `aligned` inside `equation*` or `align*` (without equation).
- a single equation number for a multiline display, use `aligned` inside `equation` or inside `gather`
- one equation number per line , use `align`
- equation numbers one some lines only, use `align` but add `\nonumber` on the lines to left unnumbered
- single equation number postfixed with a, b,c etc, enclose `align` environment inside `subequation` environment.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the `align` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
    B' &=-\nabla \times E,\\
    E' &=\nabla \times B - 4\pi j
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Change the equations for those you need.

If you don't want them labeled put an * right after align like: `\begin{align*} math \end{align*}`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using the `amsmath` package or the `mathtools`. Here is a MWE

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{mathtools}

    \begin{document}
\[
    \begin{aligned}[t]
    \phi^\lambda_\sigma A_t &= \sum_{\pi\in C_t} sgn(\pi)\phi^\lambda_\sigma\phi^\lambda_\pi \\
                 &= \sum_{\tau\in C_{\sigma t}} sgn(\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma)\phi^\lambda_\sigma\phi^\lambda_{\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma}\\
                 &= A_{\sigma t \phi^\lambda_\sigma}
    \end{aligned}
\]
    \end{document}
```

A similar answer can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394568/align-multi-lines-equations)