# using \begin{equation} but cannot align equation and want to show only one number of equation

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I want to write these equations using the \begin{equation} , however can't align them to the left side and want to put only one reference number for them

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S=-\frac{1}{2}\rho v \delta \left(\frac{\ mu}{pF}\right)^{1/2} e \sin{\theta} \\
T = -\frac{1}{2}\rho v \delta \left(\frac{\mu}{pF}\right)^{1/2} \left( 1+e \cos{\theta}- r\alpha \left(\frac{p}{\mu}\right)^{1/2} \cos{i} \right)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

this is the output of my code 
[image]

but i want to align my equations like in the following picture

[image]

help me thanks :)

Comment: What you is left-aligned, or do I misunderstand what you want?

Comment: I also have some trouble understanding your question. Could you show a screenshot of the output you have now, and a mockup screenshot of the output that you want to have?

Comment: edited , the first picture is my output , the second picture is the output that i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't produce the image.

However, use the proper markup:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
S &= -\frac{1}{2}\rho v \delta \left(\frac{\mu}{pF}\right)^{\!1/2} e \sin\theta \\
T &= -\frac{1}{2}\rho v \delta \left(\frac{\mu}{pF}\right)^{\!1/2}
      \biggl( 1+e \cos\theta- r\alpha \left(\frac{p}{\mu}\right)^{\!1/2} \cos i \biggr) \\
W &= -\frac{1}{2}\rho v \delta \frac{r\alpha}{\sqrt{F}}\sin i \cos(\omega+\theta)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Note that I changed `\left(` and `\right)` to `\biggl(` and `\biggr)` that produce correctly sized fences. Also `\sin{\theta}` can be more simply `\sin\theta`.

I also added a negative thin space to the exponents, in order not to have them too far from the parenthesis.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My humble proposal. You can replace each of your equations with a, b, c, d and e.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Name}
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned} 
    a&= b \\
    c&= d \\
    e&= f 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

For example:

```
S& =-\frac{1}{2}\rho v \delta \left(\frac{\mu}{pF}\right)^{1/2} e \sin\theta \\
```

instead of `a&= b`

Comment: For a more systematic handling of numbering you could have a look to my  answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/470400/33514

Comment: @Jhor Welcome :-) Thank you very much for your detailed answer. If you prefer you are authorized to edit my code. There is no problem for me.